# How to access currently logged in user information from a c++ program which is running as service?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am able to retrieve currently logged in user information through my C++ program which is running in IDE. After I changed it into service and try to get the information, I couldn't. What is the issue with that?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to expect a service to be able to automatically see "the" information for "the" logged on user - what if more than one user is logged on?  What if nobody is logged on?

Answer (score 3):

When you run desktop application, that is not as a service, it runs under the user you are logged in as.

When your program is running as a service, it defaults to be running using the [`LocalSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) user.

If you want to run as another user, you need to specify it using the `lpServiceStartName` argument in the [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.

Comment: For completeness, you can also manually change the user a service runs as through the "Services" component.